# Mock Apache ActiveMq with amqp protocol

Tags: activemq-classic, amqp

We are using solace as the Messaging system in our application and while writing the unit test classes (using JUNIT )for listners i have to start the solcae in my local.
Instead i was trying to mock the broker  (apache ActiveMq) to use amqp protocl and send messages to the listeners.
https://github.com/apache/activemq/blob/activemq-5.15.x/activemq-amqp/src/test/java/org/apache/activemq/transport/amqp/AmqpTransformerTest.java

But when i try to build the maven project i see the error

package org.apache.activemq.transport.amqp.client does not exist.

I have added the below dependencies but i still facing the same issue. Please suggest

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
            <artifactId>activemq-broker</artifactId>
            <version>5.15.12</version>
            <!-- <scope>test</scope> -->
        </dependency>

        <!-- Testing Dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.qpid</groupId>
            <artifactId>qpid-jms-client</artifactId>
            <version>0.51.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
            <artifactId>activemq-kahadb-store</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
            <artifactId>activemq-jaas</artifactId>
            <version>5.15.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
            <artifactId>activemq-broker</artifactId>
            <version>5.15.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
            <artifactId>activemq-spring</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
            <artifactId>activemq-http</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
            <artifactId>activemq-mqtt</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
            <artifactId>activemq-leveldb-store</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.activemq.tooling</groupId>
            <artifactId>activemq-junit</artifactId>
            <version>5.15.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

I am not able to resolve the below compilation issues.
org.apache.activemq.transport.amqp.client can not be resolved since the dependecy for this package is not found,But i have added the above dependencies in the maven project.

```
import org.apache.activemq.transport.amqp.client.AmqpClient;
import org.apache.activemq.transport.amqp.client.AmqpConnection;
import org.apache.activemq.transport.amqp.client.AmqpMessage;
import org.apache.activemq.transport.amqp.client.AmqpSender;
import org.apache.activemq.transport.amqp.client.AmqpSession;
```

Please suggest.
thank you experts.

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely clear what your test is doing but the classes it can't find are those of the AMQP test client that is implemented in the ActiveMQ 5.x AMQP module's test jar so you definitely won't find them with the dependencies you have there.

The AMQP test client in the ActiveMQ broker is not meant for general use by anyone as is was built specifically to test the AMQP stack in the broker.  If you remove the usage of that from your tests you should have better luck.